# Duplicating uv vertices?

Tags: uv

I downloaded an already made model

while i was adjusting the model, and removing doubles a hole appeared on the mesh

[image]

when i tried to fill the hole i expected something like the right side of the picture, but got this

[image]

is there a way i can add a vertex like the right side of the picture?

Comment: Did you try un unwrap again your model?

Comment: yes but im using an already made image texture and cant get the same uvmap when i unwrap it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UV editor:

1. Select all and Pin all UV coordinates
2. Select the UV faces that you have added
3. Reset UVs and Unpin them
4. Unwrap
5. Select all and Unpin